# The meaning of "Very" in a particular sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "Very" in this sentence:

> He started flailing professionally and found out how hard it is to
>   deal with the **very** treatment he himself once dished out.

Comment: "Flailing professionally"? O_o Could it be "failing"?

Comment: very is used for emphasis in the sentence. He found out how it is to deal with the treatment - not any other, but the exact treatment that he himself once dished out. https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/very, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/very#british-1-2-1

Comment: @CowperKettle Possibly [***flail***](https://www.google.com/search?q=flailing+synonym&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) - flounder; struggle uselessly. "I was *flailing* about in the water.", though I didn't check the linked article.

Comment: Maybe he was a miller? The flailer flailed.  Knockoff of *L'Arroseur Arrosé*

Comment: The word very has been used in the sentence to emphasize the noun treatment; it conveys the sense of exact or the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a question answerable from any [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/very).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your excerpt

> the **very** treatment

is a shorter way to say

> the **very same** treatment

as he himself once dished out